# Migration tool for Synology NAS to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

I have a requirement to migrate files from Synology NAS to SharePoint Online.
Can please someone suggest a migration tool for the above?

In addition to the above, does the migration tool take into consideration the permissions based on how it is assigned on NAS for every user?

Finally, the total files on NAS are around 200k combination of files and folders and when the library is migrated to SharePoint they want to proceed to upload files/folders and assign permissions to users. Will anything stop them from performing those operations?

Since I know it is not recommended to store more than 30K files in a single library but it seems that they don't want to change their library structure.

Any suggestion/advice is highly appreciated based on the concerns mentioned above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to sync data from NAS Synology to SharePoint using Cloud Sync. With Cloud Sync, you can seamlessly sync and share files among your Synology NAS and multiple public cloud services, including: Microsoft SharePoint Online (document library only)

For more details: [Synology Cloud Sync](https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/help/CloudSync/cloudsync?version=6)

Comment: Hello Casey, thank you for your reply. What about this question if I have in a SharePoint library combination of files and folders around 200k and I want to continuously upload files/folders and assign permissions to users. Will anything stop me from performing those operations?

Since I know it is not recommended to store more than 30K files in a single library but it seems that they don't want to change their library structure.